# What is the difference between main() and void main() in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

What is the difference between `main()` and `void main()` in Flutter

The only answers that I could find on the internet are about C++ or sth like that.

Comment: Since Flutter isn't command line application, there is no difference at all

Comment: ``dynamic return type`` vs ``void return type`` method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, let's see:

```
void main() {
  print(main.runtimeType);
}
```

will print `() => void`. That means a function with no parameters returning void.

While

```
main() {
  print(main.runtimeType);
}
```

will print `() => dynamic`. That means a function with no parameters returning dynamic.

The valid return type for the `main` function is `void`:

> Every app must have a top-level main() function, which serves as the entrypoint to the app. The main() function returns void and has an optional List<String> parameter for arguments.

[Source](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#the-main-function)

So strictly speaking, having no return type (that means defaulting to the type `dynamic`) is wrong. But that is the simplified beginners instructions, so there are exceptions. But when in doubt, do it by the book.

Answer (score 0):

the different is when return a value from the function in `void read()` you can't return any type of value ..
While in `read()`you can return any type of value weather is int , double , String , list and also a set **Because it's dynamic** also you can type `dynamic read()` it's same as `read()`

```
void main () {
// print(iifo.runtimeType);
var k = iifo() ;
print(k) ;
}
  iifo ( ) {
 return ('Stack') ;
 }
```

output
Stack

in return line you can return any type of data (int , double , String , bool , list, etc....).

Answer (score 0):

This answer does not address your question directly, since I see that it has been already answered properly. However, you might find good to know that the `main` function in a Dart application can also return `Future<void>` instead of `void`, since you can tag the `main` function as an `async` function.

In the particular case of a Flutter application, this means that you can do whatever you need to do before running `runApp(...)` in the `main()` method body, **even asynchronously**. This way, the splash screen will be shown until your asynchronous result is retrieved, before calling `runApp(...)`. For example, setting a landing widget depending on the result of an asynchronous task:

```
Future<void> main() async {
    // Do whatever you need to do here
    final home = await createHomeWidgetDependingOnAsyncResult();
    return runApp(MyApp(home: home));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found it the problem, I wrote:

```
import 'LanguagesScreen.dart';
```

Instead of:

```
import 'package:flutter_projects/LanguagesScreen.dart';
```